# What is the common practice (if there are any) of implementing barrels in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

Well, by doing some research I realized that this is something that nobody is doing)

But if there are some common practices I would like to know about them.

Just for sake of example here is how I'm doing it:

**first.component.js**

```
class FirstComponent {
  firstMethod() {
    console.log("I'm first")
  }
}

module.exports = { FirstComponent }
```

**instance.export.js**

```
class InstanceExport {
  instanceMethod() {
    console.log("I'm instance")
  }
}
module.exports = new InstanceExport()
```

**index.js**

```
const { FirstComponent } = require("./first.component")
const InstanceExport = require("./instance.export")

module.exports = { FirstComponent, InstanceExport }
```

**app.js**

```
const { FirstComponent, InstanceExport } = require("./src/components")

let first = new FirstComponent()
first.firstMethod()

InstanceExport.instanceMethod()
```

Is this the best way I can achieve the barrel pattern? (without babel, typescript, any side libs etc.)

Maybe I can reduce the amount of code inside `index.js`.
Also does this approach (not the barrel itself, but the one I described above) has some super dangerous downsides?

Comment: Best practice and optimisation questions belong on [codereview.se].

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that. I'll try to search there